# How to Sort list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

I trying to sort this list by pressing the sort button? im having trouble with the coding part!

Comment: can you paste code you have tried?

Comment: @KevinChun where did you post it?

Comment: All good i got it too work haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head (I can't test it myself right now), I would do this:

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> list = lstbxResults.Cast<string>().OrderBy(p=>p).ToList();

    lstbxResults.Clear();
    foreach(var item in list)
        lstbxResults.Items.Add(item);
}
```

edit: I put a Cast to obtain an IEnumerable

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   private void btnSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
            {  
             var directoryInfo= new directoryInfo(path);

            var files = (from x in directoryInfo.GetFiles()
                         select x.FullName).ToArray();

            Array.Sort(files);


            }
```

Comment: i tried this however it doesnt sort it still, the code is posted above, i cant figure it out for some reason